# dplyr filter by group conditionally with if else

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, group-by, dplyr

After using `group_by` in dplyr I would like to use `filter` to sample all rows in a group if there are fewer than x rows while if there are more than x rows I would like to sub-sample a specific number of rows from those groups. I'll illustrate with the diamonds data set when grouped by clarity.

```
diamonds %>%
    group_by(clarity) %>%
    summarise(count = n())
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  clarity count
  <ord>   <int>
1 I1        741
2 SI2      9194
3 SI1     13065
4 VS2     12258
5 VS1      8171
6 VVS2     5066
7 VVS1     3655
8 IF       1790
```

Using this example I want to sample all rows in clarity groups if they have 5066 or fewer rows while in groups with more than 5066 rows I would like to use `sample_n` without replacement to randomly sample 5000 rows. `sample_n` without replacement will only work if `size` is equal to or less than the number of rows in the smallest group. I'm stuck after trying a number of things but here is an example of my thought process.

```
diamonds %>%
  group_by(clarity) %>%
  if_else(n() > 5066, sample_n(size = 5000, replace = F), filter())
```

I'm pretty new to dplyr and still getting familiar with R in general. I'm sure this is something relatively easy but I did not see a clear solution posted. Thanks in advance!

**edit:**

Pretty much I would like the output from the following code but in one line of code.

```
# groups below or equal to 5066
low_sample_groups <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(clarity) %>% 
  filter( n() <= 5066)

# groups above 5066
high_sample_groups <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(clarity) %>% 
  filter( n() > 5066) %>%
  sample_n(size = 5000, replace = F)

desired_result <- full_join(low_sample_groups, high_sample_groups)
```

**edit round 2**

found the answer I was looking for here: [custom grouped dplyr function (sample_n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676368/custom-grouped-dplyr-function-sample-n/55676429#55676429)

Essentially this is the solution using an if statement

```
n <- 5066
desired_result <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(clarity) %>% 
  sample_n(if(n() < n) n() else n)
```

Comment: (1) You can rewrite the first chain as `diamonds %>% count(clarity)` which is more succinct. (2) *"sub-sample a specific number of rows from those groups"* I'm not sure I understand your question; `group_by` plus `summarise` reduces entries to *one row per group*. In other words, you can't sample from multiple rows per group because there is only one.

Comment: @MauritsEvers sorry if that isn't clear but with the first block of code I was just trying to show counts for each group.The second block of code is what I was using to actually try to get at the problem.

Comment: So the source data does in fact have multiple rows per group? If that is the case, can you please provide some *representative* sample data? Because the first code block generates sample data that has only one row per group (by construction).

Answer (score 3):

We can start by `split` "group" the data frame by required variable then apply "`map`" a conditional sampling based on the number of observations within each group.

```
diamonds %>% split(.$clarity) %>% 
             map(function(x) if (nrow(x) <= 5066) sample_n(size = nrow(x), replace = F,x) else sample_n(size = 5000, replace = F,x)) %>% bind_rows()
```

More concisely

```
Sample_FUN <- function(x){
              if (nrow(x) <= 5000) sample_n(size = nrow(x), replace = F,x) 
              else sample_n(size = 5066, replace = F,x)
              } 

diamonds %>% split(.$clarity) %>% map(Sample_FUN) %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: This is a great start but the output is a list of the dataframes output from the function. I'm looking to get the code to return a single dataframe with the rows meeting the criteria outlined in the function. I was able to do it in a messy way that I'll post now to the original question.